Sidebar menu doesn't appear because of animation
I am doing an app in flutter and I try to use rive animation . I added a gesture detector container in the appBar but I wanted it to show up on the left side. Each time I am touching the Button the animation it's playing but the sidebar doesn't show up. Any idea what I should do? here it's a video https://imgur.com/a/anes9dP
And below I added the code
import 'package:INFLUFIT/MyProfile_business.dart';
import 'package:INFLUFIT/theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';

import 'package:rive/rive.dart';
import 'post_detail.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flashy_tab_bar2/flashy_tab_bar2.dart';
import 'Influencerprofile.dart';
import 'package:liquid_pull_to_refresh/liquid_pull_to_refresh.dart';
import 'add_content.dart';
import 'sidebar_menu.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  late Animation<double> _sidebarAnim;
  late SMIBool _menuBtn;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> tabItems = [
    Center(child: Text("0")),
    Center(child: Text("1")),
    Center(child: Text("2")),
    Center(child: Text("3")),
    Center(child: Text("4"))
  ];
  final springDesc =
      const SpringDescription(mass: 0.1, stiffness: 40, damping: 5);

  void _onMenuIconInit(Artboard artboard) {
    final controller =
        StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, "State Machine");
    artboard.addController(controller!);
    _menuBtn = controller.findInput<bool>("isOpen") as SMIBool;
    _menuBtn.value = true;
  }

  void onMenuPress() {
    if (_menuBtn.value) {
      final springAnim = SpringSimulation(springDesc, 0, 1, 0);
      _animationController?.animateWith(springAnim);
    } else {
      _animationController?.reverse();
    }
    _menuBtn.change(!_menuBtn.value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      upperBound: 1,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _sidebarAnim = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.linear));

    // _tabBody = _screens.first;
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _handleRefresh() async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        actions: <Widget>[
          AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _sidebarAnim,
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(_sidebarAnim.value * 265, 0),
                  child: child,
                );
              }),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: onMenuPress,
            child: Container(
              width: 70,
              height: 70,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70 / 2),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: RiveAppTheme.shadow.withOpacity(0.2),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        offset: const Offset(0, 5))
                  ]),
              child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                '/Users/lilianasanda/influfit/assets/rive/menu_button.riv',
                stateMachines: const ["State Machine"],
                animations: const ["open", "close"],
                onInit: _onMenuIconInit,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
        title: Text(
          'INFLUFIT.CLUB',
          style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
              child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, children: [
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search influencer",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                    )))
          ])),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(
                'Location',
                style: TextStyle(),
              )),
          Expanded(
            child: LiquidPullToRefresh(
              //  key: _refreshIndicatorKey, // key if you want to add
              onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: tabItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostDetail(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FlashyTabBar(
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showElevation: true,
        onItemSelected: (index) => setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        }),
        items: [
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: InkWell(
              child: Icon(Icons.home),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                );
              },
            ),
            title: Text('Feed'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: Text('Favourites'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: InkWell(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ContentPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
            title: InkWell(
              child: Text('Add'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ContentPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
            ),
            title: Text('News'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: InkWell(
              child: Icon(Icons.person),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BusinessPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
            title: InkWell(
              child: Text('My profile'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BusinessPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

